# Simple rule for closing a TCP protocol

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am using Java to design a system where many servers open TCP connections with each other to send relatively small amounts of data (say less than 5KB). Under normal load everything works. But when I stress the system, some of my protocols throw exceptions. The cause for the exceptions is that when a peer A finishes writing data, it calls .flush() on the OutputStream and closes the socket. The OS of peer B terminates the connection before B has a chance to finish reading all of the data, resulting in an exception.

I suspect that stressing the system exacerbates this issue because it reduces the amount of time available to the thread of B to read data from the socket, but I’m not sure.

I’ve seen a recommendation to fix this problem by having the Client initiate the close of the socket.
However, it’s not clear to me who is the client. Both A and B may send multiple messages to each other during the protocol.

So I now wonder if someone could recommend a simple rule for which side should close the connection, and how. Based on what I read, I think the side that reads the last message of the protocol should close it. Regarding how to close the connection, say peer B receives the last message. So a simple solution would be to have B send one byte to A, and close the socket. A waits for this byte, and then closes the socket.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What error is B getting? Can you post some code? B shouldn't get an exception when A closes the socket. It should still be able to read all of the pending data before it hits EOF. The OS will store the unread data in a buffer; it won't throw it away. It would be helpful if you could create a [mre] with code and full error messages that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Last time I ran it I got this (I know it's a write exception, which is different from what I describe above (where it's a read exception). But it's the same thing. For some reason the socket is closed by one side before the other has a chance to finish writing)

    **java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
   java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:141)**

Comment: A write exception is okay. It's telling you the other side has closed the connection so there's no point in trying to write anything cause there's nobody listening. Just don't treat it as a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more reading it seems that when a socket is closed, there is an exchange of FIN ACK messages. I think it’s called graceful close (as opposed to forceful close). Those messages are not really messages, but just flags in the packets; the packets may also carry data that is being written by the peers. When data is received, it is stored in the receive buffer, even if those flags are set. The key point is that data can be read from the buffer even after the socket is closed. However, it cannot be written to the socket after the socket is closed. Please correct me if I’m wrong.

So, it’s ok for A to write to B, let A close A’s side of the socket, let B do the reading, and then let B close B’s side of the socket.

Regarding the issue described in my question, I found out that what actually happened is this:
A initiates the protocol with B.
B is doing pre-work that’s taking too long and is protected by a timeout. Because this code is inside a try-with-resources clause on the socket, when the timeout happens, the thread is first interrupted and then the socket is closed.
B’s code is inside a wrapper class that checks if exceptions happened during protocol execution. If so, it writes an error code to A. But because the socket is closed, the write operation fails.
A in the meantime is not aware of the timeout and starts writing data to B. So A gets an exception too

Answer (score -2):

There is a method `Socket.shutdownInput()` that allows one side to close one of the directions. The other end will get EOF and can then close the socket.

Comment: `shutdownInput()` doesn't cause EOF at the peer. You are thinking of `shutdownOutput()`, but `close()` has exactly the same effect.